# Why is not a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I write this class:

```
class Sensor:
    def __init__ (self,sensor_class_name, data):
        self.sensor_class_name = sensor_class_name
        self.data              = data
```

When I do this check:

```
if type(Sensor) == type:
    print("type")

else:
    print("not type")
```

It returns `not type`.

When I do this check on built in class, it returns `type`.

Why `Sensor` is not a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a class of the old (pre 2.2) Python using a *plain* class statement.

```
>>> type(Sensor)
<type 'classobj'>
```

Try:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.ClassType is type(Sensor)
True
```

A `class` statement without *bases* creates a *classic* class. In order to create a new style class you have to specify `object` as the base.

`types.ClassType` resembles  `<type 'type'>`, *instances* of it are *types*.

Answer (score 0):

In new style classes so that inherite from `object` class every `class object` is `instance` of `type` class.

```
print isinstance(Sensor, type) # True

    class Sensor:
        def __init__ (self,sensor_class_name, data):
            ..
            ..
    if type(Sensor) == type:
        print("type")  
    else:
        print("not type")
    print isinstance(Sensor, type)

Ouput:-
    >>> 
    not type
    Flase
```

While in `newstyle classes` :-

```
class Sensor(object):
     ...
     ...
print isinstance(Sensor, type)
>>> 
type
True
```

also:-

```
In [52]: class A: pass

In [53]: type(A)
Out[53]: classobj

In [54]: class B(object):pass

In [55]: type(B)
Out[55]: type

In [56]: B.__class__
Out[56]: type

In [57]: A.__class__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-5b54bd730948> in <module>()
----> 1 A.__class__

AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__class__'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import types
>>> dir(types)
['BooleanType', 'BufferType', 'BuiltinFunctionType', 'BuiltinMethodType', 'ClassType', 'CodeType', 'ComplexType', 'DictProxyType', 'DictType', 'DictionaryType', 'EllipsisType', 'FileType', 'FloatType', 'FrameType', 'FunctionType', 'GeneratorType', 'GetSetDescriptorType', 'InstanceType', 'IntType', 'LambdaType', 'ListType', 'LongType', 'MemberDescriptorType', 'MethodType', 'ModuleType', 'NoneType', 'NotImplementedType', 'ObjectType', 'SliceType', 'StringType', 'StringTypes', 'TracebackType', 'TupleType', 'TypeType', 'UnboundMethodType', 'UnicodeType', 'XRangeType', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']

>>> class Sensor:
...     pass
... 
>>> if type(Sensor) == types.ClassType:
...     print "type"
... else:
...     print "not type"
... 
type
>>> type(type)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(Sensor)
<type 'classobj'>
```

`type` itself is type of `types` module.

`Class` is type of `ClassType`.

Answer (score 0):

Because types derive from objects:

In python2 classes without a parent class are type classobj. In python3 this changed and classes without parent class the inherit by default from object.

```
class A: pass
print type(A)
<type 'classobj'>


class B(object): pass
print type(B)
<type 'type'>
```

check this link for more info:https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass

Answer (score 0):

In ancient versions of Python (before v2.2) a class was a special thing (`classobj`), separate from a `type`:

```
>>> class OldStyleClass:
...     pass
...
>>> type(OldStyleClass)
<type 'classobj'>
```

This is an ["old style class"](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)

Python 2.2 onwards you should generally always use "new style" classes, which are defined by inheriting from `object` (or some subclass of it):

```
>>> class NewStyleClass(object):
...     pass
...
>>> type(NewStyleClass)
<type 'type'>
```

There is a good post about the history of classes in Python, explaining the distinction - ["New-style Classes" on The History of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.com.au/2010/06/new-style-classes.html) blog (written by the creator of Python)

In Python 3, this distinction was removed, so both of the class definitions above would be identical:

```
>>> class Blah:
...     pass
...
>>> type(Blah)
<class 'type'>
>>>
>>> class Blah(object):
...     pass
...
>>> type(Blah)
<class 'type'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just inherit the class from object, and now it say it a class.

```
class Sensor (object):
    def __init__ (self,sensor_class_name, data):
        self.sensor_class_name = sensor_class_name
        self.data              = data
```